# I am running my flask-restful API on GCP Cloud Build. Why am I getting an error 400?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, python-requests, google-api-python-client, http-status-code-400

Here is my API code, which worked locally, but not on GCP -

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api, Resource, reqparse

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

put_args = reqparse.RequestParser()
put_args.add_argument("question", type=str, help="Enter your question", required=True)


class ZeroOrOne(Resource):
    def get(self):
        args = put_args.parse_args()
        if(len(args["question"])%2 == 0):
            return {"value" : 0}
        else:
            return {"value": 1}

api.add_resource(ZeroOrOne, "/zeroorone")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

Here is my request -

```
import requests

url = "<here-is-my-private-base-url>/zeroorone"

question = "Hey, how are you"
response = requests.get(url, json={"question": question})
print(response.json())
```

When I ran this API locally, it worked. But on GCP it does not.

I tried putting a headers in the GET request and also put the "json=" as done above. But nothing is working.

Comment: More information is needed - which GCP service are you using (GAE, Cloud Run, GCE, etc)? How are you trying to access your endpoint (you type a url in the browser, you use POSTMAN, etc)? Show us the payload or url you use

Comment: Plus show how you are deploying, the deployment files, and the log entries for this error.